# Firebase Error android unreachable statement

Tags: java, android

Unreachable statement error in `mFirebaseAuth.signOut();` in option item selected area.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  switch (item.getItemId()) {               
       case R.id.sign_out_menu:
          mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
          Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
          mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
          startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
          return true;
       default:
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); on top line number 2 solved.

Answer (score 2):

Remove ,

```
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Answer (score -1):

from this line on your code:

```
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

delete the word "return" so your new line appears like this:

```
super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, this answer doesn't really add anything the other answers don't already state.